# unable to proxy a PDF file in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, pdf, proxy

I need to download a pdf from an endpoint I receive from an external service, store the pdf in my database and send it back to the browser (or whoever is calling the API on my system).
For some reasons I can't understand if I put the service's URL directly on the browser it opens the pdf correctly, but if I run this code

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');

var app = express();
var _PORT = 9008;

console.log("starting server on port " + _PORT);

// will return an unordered list of all items.
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log("Proxying stuff");

    var get_options = {
        'rejectUnauthorized': false,
        'url': 'http://www.urartuuniversity.com/content_images/pdf-sample.pdf',
        'method': 'GET'
    };

    request(get_options, function(err, get_resp, body){
        if(err){
            console.log(err.message);
            res.json({error: err})
        }

        console.log('data received from service:' + body.length);

        res.type('application/pdf');
        res.end(body);
    });
});

app.listen(_PORT);
```

by calling `localhost:9008/` from the browser I only get 2 blank pages. I kind of tried them all changing all possible configurations and encodings but so far I only got blank pages.

In case you need more informations please ask.

Comment: What does `body` contain? It its the entire pdf, use `res.sendFile` http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.sendFile

Comment: this way I can send a file stored locally on my machine, but I need to proxy it from another url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I finally found how to do it:

```
request
    .get('http://www.urartuuniversity.com/content_images/pdf-sample.pdf')
    .on('response', function(response) {

        var chunks = [];
        response.on('data', function(chunk){
            chunks.push(chunk);
        });

        response.on('end', function(){
            var finalData = new Buffer.concat(chunks);
            myDatabase.store(finalData);

            res.type('application/pdf');
            res.end(finalData, 'binary');
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Pleae change

```
var get_options = {
        'rejectUnauthorized': false,
        'url': 'http://www.urartuuniversity.com/content_images/pdf-sample.pdf',
        'method': 'GET'
    };

    request(get_options, function(err, get_resp, body){
        if(err){
            console.log(err.message);
            res.json({error: err})
        }

        console.log('data received from service:' + body.length);

        res.type('application/pdf');
        res.end(body);
    });
```

to

```
request
  .get('http://www.urartuuniversity.com/content_images/pdf-sample.pdf')
  .on('response', function(response) {
    console.log(response.statusCode) 
    console.log(response.headers['content-type'])
  })
  .on('end', function(){
     // store pdf into DB here.
     fs.createReadStream('pdf-sample.pdf').pipe(res); // send the pdf to client
  })
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('pdf-sample.pdf')) //store the pdf in your server
```

Comment: This way works fine, so a problem is fixed, but I still need to store the pdf on my DB and this way I cannot access the body, correct?

Comment: `  .pipe(pipe(fs.createWriteStream('pdf-sample.pdf'))) //store the pdf in your server, then you can store in to your DB.` is crashing. and in the callback of on('end', function...) I have no available params, so how should I get the data to store on DB?

Comment: @bncc please try again.

Comment: this way works fine, although I still haven't understand how to store the file on the DB: to do so I need to cast it to a Buffer and then store it

Answer (score 0):

This could be super easy as

```
app.use('/pdf', (req, res) => {
  let url = 'http://www.urartuuniversity.com/content_images/pdf-sample.pdf';
  let src = request(url);
  req.pipe(src).pipe(res);
});
```

You don't have to store data on the server this way.